# Add 20px of padding to Content Block HTML

Tags: html

I need to add padding to a content block in salesforce marketing cloud so that when the block is dynamically inserted into an email next to another block, it will have 20px white space in-between. There is padding within the HTML but it's part of the block that has a color background so when I try to add padding it's colored vs white. What is the easiest way to add that additional 20px padding outside of the colored table background?

```
<table bgcolor="#DDF0F2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 
  <tr>
   <td style="color:#086C78; font-family: Montserrat, Verdana, sans-serif; line-height:1.2; font-weight: 800; text-align:center; padding: 20px 20px 10px 20px;">
    <h1>
     Use your %%=v(@creditAmount)=%% travel credit</h1>&nbsp;<p style="font-family: Nunito, Verdana, sans-serif; color: #086C78; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5; font-weight: 700; margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px; text-align: center;">
     Enter the code %%=v(@promoCode)=%% when you checkout at <a alias="Evolve" href="https://evolve.com/" style="font-family: Nunito, Verdana, sans-serif; color: #086C78; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5; font-weight: 700; margin: 0px; text-align: center;">evolve.com</a> to get more bang for your budget. Your credit expires on %%=v(@expirationDate)=%%.</p></td></tr><tr>
   <td style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     
      <tr>
       <td align="center" bgcolor="#093F45" class="block noLeftRightPad padBot20" style="background: #093F45; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; padding-left:20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px; vertical-align:middle;" valign="middle" width="50%">
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
         
          <tr>
           <td align="center" class="mobilefont-16-18" style="font-family:Nunito,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:#ffffff; font-size:18px; line-height: 18px; font-weight: 900; padding-bottom:10px;">
            Travel Credit</td></tr><tr>
           <td align="center" class="mobilefont-29-44" style="font-family:Nunito,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:#ffffff; font-size: 36px; font-weight: 900; line-height: 36px;padding-bottom:10px;">
            %%=v(@UnappliedTC)=%%</td></tr><tr>
           <td align="center" class="mobilefont-16-18">
            <span style="font-family:'Montserrat',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:#ffffff; font-size:14px; line-height: 18px;">Expires on:</span> <span style="font-family:'Montserrat',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:#ffffff; font-size:14px; line-height: 18px; font-weight:600;">%%=v(@validThrough)=%%</span></td></tr></table></td><td align="center" class="block" width="20">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
         
          <tr>
           <td style="padding-left: 20px;">
            &nbsp;</td></tr></table></td><td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="block noLeftRightPad" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; padding-left:20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px; vertical-align:middle;" valign="middle" width="50%">
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
         
          <tr>
           <td align="center" class="mobilefont-16-18" style="font-family:'Montserrat',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:#086C78; font-size:14px; line-height: 18px;padding-bottom:15px;">
            Apply Promo Code:</td></tr><tr>
           <td align="center" class="mobilefont-29-44" style="font-family:Nunito,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:#086C78; font-size:24px; line-height: 36px; font-weight: 900;padding-bottom:15px;">
            %%=v(@promoCode)=%%</td></tr><tr>
           <td align="center" class="mobilefont-16-18" style="font-family:'Montserrat',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:#086C78; font-size:14px; line-height: 18px;">
            Upon checkout at <a alias="evolve" href="%%=RedirectTo(@evolve)=%%" style="color:#1ab2c5;text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank">evolve.com</a>.</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
```

I've tried adding padding to the  but it's just adding more colored block area, How to I add white space padding surrounding that?

Comment: Have you tried adding 20px padding to the table?

Comment: If you want spacing *outside* the element instead of *inside* the element then aren't you looking for `margin` instead of `padding`?

Comment: Note that the `align` attribute has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for 20 years or more.